# Is this JSON valid? I'm getting an end of file expected error in VScode

Tags: python, json, visual-studio-code

Here is the JSON output/ The error gets flagged on the 2nd opening parenthesis.

```
{
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "1",
    "Company": "General Motors",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "9823.5",
    "Profit (in millions)": "806"
}{
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "2",
    "Company": "Exxon Mobil",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "5661.4",
    "Profit (in millions)": "584.8"
}{
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "3",
    "Company": "U.S. Steel",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "3250.4",
    "Profit (in millions)": "195.4"
}{
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "4",
    "Company": "General Electric",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "2959.1",
    "Profit (in millions)": "212.6"
}
```

Here's the code which generates the file.

```
#Json File
    newfile= open("data2.json", "w", newline="")
    for rows in parse:
        try:
            (float(rows["Profit (in millions)"]))#This validates that the value in this column is a number. 
            newfile.write(json.dumps(rows, indent=4))
            
            
            
        except ValueError:
            pass
```

Please let me know if anything looks off to you.

Comment: `newfile.write(json.dumps(parse, indent=4))` to produce valid JSON, float validation is left as an exercise to the reader.

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects should be separated by commas. Arrays should be enclosed in square brackets. So your JSON should look like this `[{...}, {...}, ...]`.

Comment: So a comma in between the close and open parenthesis?

Comment: @Crimson Yes, just insert a comma between curly brackets. And you need to enclose your objects with square brackets as well to make them an array

Comment: @Crimson I've just updated the answer because square brackets were missed as well

Answer (score 0):

JSON is easy, but it does have a few rules. Most of the time, your JSON file structure violates one of these :

1. Array elements should be separated by a comma.
2. Everything must be wrapped in one single root object, which can be an Object {} or an Array {}. Multiple root object is not allowed.
3. Special characters must be escaped. Pay attention closely to double quotes and Unicode double-quotes. Here's a list of special, reserved characters in JSON :
4. Backspace should be escaped with b.
5. Form feed should be escaped with f.
6. Newline should be escaped with n.
7. Carriage return should be escaped with r.
8. Tab should be escaped with t.
9. Double quote should be escaped with "

Answer (score 0):

You can check it with a JSON validator.

For example: https://jsonlint.com/

Below image is your JSON data validation result on JSONLint. You missed the comma between the JSON objects. In addition, you need to add square brackets `[]` to make it becomes an array of objects.

[image: Your JSON data validation result on JSONLint]

Here is the updated version of your JSON data.

```json
[{
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "1",
    "Company": "General Motors",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "9823.5",
    "Profit (in millions)": "806"
}, {
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "2",
    "Company": "Exxon Mobil",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "5661.4",
    "Profit (in millions)": "584.8"
}, {
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "3",
    "Company": "U.S. Steel",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "3250.4",
    "Profit (in millions)": "195.4"
}, {
    "Year": "1955",
    "Rank": "4",
    "Company": "General Electric",
    "Revenue (in millions)": "2959.1",
    "Profit (in millions)": "212.6"
}]
```